# typescript addEventListener using bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom-events

I have a question...Is there an option to add one EventListener for clicks in TS as there is in JS - **bubbling** . For one segment in HTML only one 'onclick' Listener that has multiple children that need to give back the value.

I found this JS code, but I can't use it. Can anyone help??... since it seems as a little bit redundant to write multiple listeners for the same segment....

```js
const preview = evt => {
  const element = evt.target.closest('div[draggable]');
  if (element != null) {
    const color = element.id;
    document.querySelector('#clicked').textContent = `Clicked ${color}`;
  }
};

document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', preview);
```

```css
div[draggable] {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: move;
}

#red {
  background: red;
}

#yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

#green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="red" draggable="true">
    <span>R</span>
  </div>
  <div id="yellow" draggable="true">
    <span>Y</span>
  </div>
  <div id="green" draggable="true">
    <span>G</span>
  </div>
</section>

<p id="clicked">Click a box</p>
```

Comment: "but I can't use it" Why not? Also, the term usually used is "event delegation", which works by taking advantage of bubbling.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I managed to do it. Sorry still pretty new to this whole JS TS stuff... but thank you for the input on "event delegation"